# How to quit "Force Quit Applications" using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I've been learning lots of different programming languages when I came across AppleScript. Since I'm technically new to it, this question may seem dumb.
I need an AppleScript script to quit the "Force Quit Applications" app.
The following code doesn't work:

> tell application "Force Quit Applications" to quit

Probably it's because the process has a different name. What is the "Force Quit Applications" process name? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Apple Script to close this window:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 53 using {command down, option down} -- ESC + ALT + CMD
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell
```

This window is owned by `loginwindow` process and it's not that easy to interact with it. Here's the code to press `Force Quit` button on this window:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow"
    click button 1 of window 1 
end tell
```

However this does not work:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow"
    close window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Good answer, just makes me sad there's no way to do this without GUI scripting. Oh well. One day.